# CSS - How to apply box-shadow to a image rounded

Tags: css, image, shadow

Here is my simple CSS code:

```
header img {
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 5px #CCC ; 

}
```

This look like this:

[image]

My `logo.png` was rounded with photoshop: http://s8.postimg.org/3ws8ehaud/logo_easyjobs.png

Comment: your image is not actually rounded in CSS, to round it you have to use `border-radius:50%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/3nEuj/). Hope this helps. I used `border-radius` to make the div round.

CSS :

```
.header {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(http://s8.postimg.org/3ws8ehaud/logo_easyjobs.png) no-repeat center center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `border-radius:50%` to your image, it should look about the same and fix your shadow. But it looks like your rounded image doesn't line up perfectly with the edge of the image (Their is extra transparent space at the tops and sides). So you will need to edit it to be lined up with the edge of the canvas more perfectly.

Comment: then we can set the `background` of the `img` to `white`, which will fill the transparent area with `white` and we have a feeling of a truly rounded image like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yavnu/)

Comment: Set the background to white, good idea. It works for your logo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/3ws8ehaud/logo_easyjobs.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    width:185px;
    height:170px;
    box-shadow:10px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

And the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fQY2h/1/